# How to overlay a nav bar/burger over a image slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a home page with a responsive navbar.  When you shrink the size of the window, it collapses into a burger for mobile/tablet, which then shows the menu options vertically down the right-hand side of the page.

The home page also has an image slide show that runs automatically that is in the centre of the page.

When the window size reduces i.e to mobile size and it collapses into a burger, I can't see some of the menu options over the image slide show. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I am a newbie to HTML, CSS & also JS... any help much appreciated (:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="assets/style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script> src="app.js"</script>
    <title>Rogue Concept</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Menu Bar-->

    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>Rogue Concept</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Restoration</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Hire</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

     <!--image slider start-->

     <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">

          <!--radio buttons start-->

          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">

          <!--radio buttons end-->

          <!--slide images start-->

          <div class="slide first">
            <img src="assets/img/grant-ritchie-j0YPbvXu4t0-unsplash.jpeg" alt="" class="center">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="assets/img/grant-ritchie-jYk96oRbPwg-unsplash.jpeg" alt="" class="center">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="assets/img/jan-de-keijzer-8eudveAaeFU-unsplash.jpeg" alt="" class="center">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="assets/img/jon-flobrant-lRSChvh1Mhs-unsplash.jpeg" alt="" class="center">
          </div>

          <!--slide images end-->

          <!--automatic navigation start-->

          <div class="navigation-auto">
            <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
          </div>

          <!--automatic navigation end-->

        </div>

        <!--manual navigation start-->

        <div class="navigation-manual">
          <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
        </div>

        <!--manual navigation end-->

      </div>
      
      <!--image slider end-->

    <script src="assets/app.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}


/* Navigation Tool Bar Start */
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

}

.logo {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Navigation Tool Bar End */

/* Mobile Nav Tool Bar Start */

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color : black;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 60%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

/* Mobile Nav Tool Bar End */

/* Animation Start */

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transfrom: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
         
    }
    
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);

}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
    
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg)translate(-5px,-6px);
    
}

  .slider {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
  }
  
  .slides {
    width: 500%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    
  }
  
  .slides input{
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slide {
    width: 20%;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  
  .slide img {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  
  /*css for manual slide navigation*/
  
  .navigation-manual {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .manual-btn {
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  .manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  
  .manual-btn:hover {
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  #radio1:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #radio2:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  
  #radio3:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -40%;
  }
  
  #radio4:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  
  /*css for automatic navigation*/
  
  .navigation-auto {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 460px;
  }
  
  .navigation-auto div {
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  .navigation-auto div:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  
  #radio1:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn1 {
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  #radio2:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn2 {
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  #radio3:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn3 {
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  #radio4:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn4 {
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
```

**app.js**

```
const  navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    

    burger.addEventListener('click',() => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
            }
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
   
    
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: I think that you need to rewrite your code because you make `navigation-manual` , `slider` width is 800px and that's make them not responsive and they are overflow the page also you giving them position absolute in order to make them at the middle of page why don't you just put them inside a container and use flexbox for this container to make them in the middle  that `position: absolute` make `slider` cover your navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) in CSS for superimpose elements.

Example:

```
nav{
 z-index: 1000;
}
```